# Error : CFBundleVersion must be higher than the previously uploaded version

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, itunes, appstore-approval

I want to upload new version of my app. The old version of my app in iTunes was 2.1 and I am uploding new version as 2.2. But when i am trying to validate my app it will give an error

```
 "CFBundleVerion must be higher than the previously uploaded version".
```

I am also incrementing the CFBundleVersion as 3.0 and BundleVersion as also 3.0 from previous versions.

**My app is in Xcode 4.0.**

What can be problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the bundle version in your `info.plist`.

Your `Bundle Version` should be increased while you submit an update of your existing app.

So increase your bundle version from 1.0 to may 2.0 or may be 1.1 based on the `number of changes` and `how big your changes are`.

Here are couple of links you can refer to get more clarity on this:

[CFBundleVersion must be higher than previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754691/cfbundleversion-must-be-higher-than-previous-version)

[CFBundleVersion in the Info.plist Upload Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933093/cfbundleversion-in-the-info-plist-upload-error)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `CFBundleVerion` with the `Bundle versions string, short` in the `info.plist` file.

For example,

if `Bundle version` is `2.5` then make sure you also update `Bundle versions string, short` to `2.5 or higher number`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using XCode 5 and had the same problem. Googling for solution I found that it is an Apple's bug but they don't fix it. So I decided to do the following:

- in plist files changed my version in bundle version and bundle version short string to desired number
- deleted all archives in organizer
- created new archive and verified version
- distributed version

these worked for me
hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, first go to:

`Runner (Targets) => General Tab`

and then increase:

`Version & Build`

For example,

`Version = 1.0.0` => if `Version = 2.0.0` or `Version = 1.0.1`

and if `Build = 1` => `Build = 2`