# Can not send iOS project to the App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I can not release iOS application because of version error message. Application version is 1.2 now and it is already in App Store I want to update it to version 2.0 but this error message occur:

[image]

Comment: If you go to your app's details in iTunes Connect and click "binary details", what's the reported bundle version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update the build number also.

To automatically increment the build number read [Version vs build in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851660/version-vs-build-in-xcode-4)

Comment: Actually we just transfer this application from another account. Previous developer do exactly this: version: 1.2 version short string: 10.0 So I improve this 2.0 & 11.0 and it works ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your previous app version was 10 and now you set it to 2 (which is below 10).
Try to set the app version to 11 (or something else above 10)

Comment: You can see it in here. it is not 10 it is 1.2 :)
https://itunes.apple.com/tr/app/memurlar.net/id423994144?l=tr&mt=8

Answer (score 1):

The build number is an internal number that indicates the current state of the app. It differs from the Version number in that it's typically not user facing and doesn't denote any difference/features/upgrades like a version number typically would.
So While you are uploading your app to  the Appstore,the version number  and build number should be greater than the previous number. For example

If your previous app version was 1.0 and build number 2.0. Then next app version should be 1.1 or above  and build number  should be 2.1 or above.

Answer (score 0):

All you had to do is change the `Bundle Version from 2.0 to 3.0` and its gonna work.

**Here lies the solution to your problem :**

[CFBundleVersion must be higher than previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9760327/434898)

Comment: it did not work. I try 11.0 it works but I don't get it previous version in 1.2 not 10.