# Non monotonic move of CFStringTokenizer iphone sdk

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I got this message today. It is first time ever I've seen this

Non monotonic move of CFStringTokenizer

I pressed on my cell in table view and it pushed another viewcontroller where i started loaded data. Actually it was loaded and after that table was reloaded and I got this message.

Do you know when I can get this error? what type of error is it?
Thank you

P.S. I'm using simulator 4-inch Retina 64-bit. XCODE 5 ioOS7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only monotonic process I could find in the developer documents is bundle version in the plist. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/conceptual/cfbundles/CFBundles.pdf

The following link led me to think your bundle version might be decremented which it can't do because its monotonic. [CFBundleVersion must be higher than previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754691/cfbundleversion-must-be-higher-than-previous-version)