# iOS app only new build and not new version give two errors

Tags: ios, xcode, build

good morning. I have already putted my iPhone app in App Store, and it is already approved and in sale.

Now, I have done a little change (the text of two message box and the correct color / alignement of one label; nothing else). This is only a new build of the same version, not a new version, so I would avoid the long approval process, and I would update this new version only as a new build.

I have tried to upload it with the same procedure (in the same conditions!) which I have already followed during my first upload of my first main version (using x-code); but it doesn't work and I see the error message which you can see in the screenshot which I have putted in my dropbox account and which you can see by the following link.

Why happend? How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: You have to change the version name like 1.1 and you must have to follow the process again.

Comment: just change build not build version

Comment: @Rohitsuvagiya That is fine for TestFlight but not for app submission. Read the second error message, it is quite specific.

Comment: So, there are no way to change only the build? Sure? Thank

Comment: Your solution here so Please read here.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754691/cfbundleversion-must-be-higher-than-previous-version

Comment: @Rohitsuvagiya That is not applicable, it is about a specific version number error. The answer here is simple to increase the version number and re-submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply each submission must be a new version with a higher version number. Each submission must go through the review process. Often the review process for a small change is quicker.

Apple does not know what actually changed so must review the entire app. Surprisingly, not every app developer is honest and trustworthy—gasp!

Just up the version number and re-submit the app.

Comment: Thank for your answer... But, during the approval process of new version, the previous version stay online and available for download in the store? Second, normally how many days are necessary (more or less) to approval a new version with very little change?

Comment: Yes, the current version remains available until the new version is approved and replaced the current version. The review time is what it takes. If there is a critical flaw in an app it is possible to request an emergency review.