# Xcode / iTunesConnect wrong build version behavior

Tags: xcode, build, app-store-connect

When I try uploading a new update for one of my macOS applications I receive the following error: *(Please read to the end before assuming that I simply forgot to increment my build number - I checked similar threads)*

[image: Error Message]

I did my usual workflow:

1. Add a new version within iTunesConnect.
2. Increase version- & build number
3. Build & Archive Version for AppStore deployment.
4. Upload

I checked every single relevant file within my project. I increased the version- / build number everywhere. When I search the whole project for ***“1.22”*** I find no hit.

I checked the usual “wrong build version”-questions here and I did everything like stated there. ***May this be a bug in Xcode / Application Loader?***

**Edit:**
Here is a screenshot taken directly from the `Info.plist` file from within the `.pkg` file:
[[image: Info.plist[2]]

As you can see, the version is 1.4 and the current build is 2. I also set this for every submodule.

Comment: Did you check yours builds number in ITC on  <your_App>/TestFlight/iOS?

Comment: what is your current version approved on itunes?

Comment: It’s an macOS app. No Testflight used.

Current approved version is 1.22. I already prepared the upload of the new version on ITC though.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Since it took me some time and different phrased searches to fine the solution, I will keep this thread for reference.

In Apple’s used versioning system 1.22 is greater than 1.4 since 22 > 4. That was the error.

[CFBundleVersion must be higher than previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754691/cfbundleversion-must-be-higher-than-previous-version)