# CFBundleIdentifer In ItunesConnect is less that new bundleIdentifier

Tags: iphone, xcode

In itunes connect, under `binary details` both my

`Bundle Short Version String :  1.0`

and my

`Bundle Version : 1.0`

are both 1.0

My new update for my xCode project is 1.1.1 it is giving me this error :

P.s. i have also tried 2.2, 99.9, 12.3...

`CFBundleVersion must be higher than previous version`

I have searched and searched and everyone is giving the same answer :check itunesconnect under binary details and make sure the uploaded version is less than the version you want to upload.

WHich it is! And i only have 1 app uploaded. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this link may it helps you...I think in your plist you had not changed version of app.

[CFBundleVersion in the Info.plist Upload Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933093/cfbundleversion-in-the-info-plist-upload-error)