# CFBundleVersion in the Info.plist Upload shows Error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, info.plist

I developed iPhone app,

I successfully uploaded first version of my app in store few days before, then i made changes in my app and now i want to upload second version of my app, i made first version of app with `Bundle version 1.0`, and in my updated app i changed my `Bundle version to 2.0`.

finally when i try to validate my app from **Xcode - organizer** it shows me this error..

[image]
and here is screenshot of my `appName-info.plist` file

[image]
***Please help, i am new to iOS..***

Comment: Perhaps [this page](http://randomtype.ca/blog/fixing-bundle-version-errors/) is of use to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933093/cfbundleversion-in-the-info-plist-upload-error

Comment: When i click on **Xcode-Organizer-Archive** it shows only `QRUI`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In info plist add one more row "Bundle version". And set here 2.0