# bundle is invalid -- CFBundleVersion and CFBundleShortVersionString in Info.plist must contain a higher version -- but they do

Tags: ios, xcode

In trying to validate my app in preparation for submission to the app store, I get the following errors:

[image]

But here's a screenshot of my Info.plist, which the error messages claim list version 1.0, showing version 1.4.

[image: Info.plist]

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this is a duplicate of [CFBundleVersion in the Info.plist Upload Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933093/cfbundleversion-in-the-info-plist-upload-error). I followed the advice in the second answer--deleting the archives--and everything turned out fine.

Comment: Same thing here!  You have to first Archive (Product menu->Archive) the app before attempting to distribute it.  It's been quite a while since I pushed out a new version, so I forgot this step....

Answer (score 4):

Apple considers each version level (`.`-separated) as a separate integer, so your old version is major 1, minor 134. That's probably not what you intended (1.1.3.4?), but you're stuck with it. I believe you will need to pick a version with either major > 1 (2.0) or minor > 134 (1.135).

```
1.0 < 1.1 < 1.2 < 1.134 < 1.135 < 1.1234 < 2.0
```

```
Major 1
   Minor 0   
   Minor 1   
   Minor 2   
   Minor 134   
   Minor 135
   Minor 1234
Major 2
   Minor 0
```

Comment: Bizarrely, even changing it to 2.0 doesn't fix the problem. The error messages still say "The value for key CFBundleVersion [1.0]" rather than "The value for key CFBundleVersion [2.0]" [or, previously, "The value for key CFBundleVersion [1.14]," etc.], so it seems to me that somewhere the fact that I've changed the version number from 1.0 isn't registering.

Answer (score 2):

Change `1.1310` by `1.135` or a number higher than `1.134` (`1.1341` will work)

You need to have a bundle version higher than the last one.
Modify the key `Bundle versions string, short` and `Bundle version`.

Furthermore, be careful of the first warning and add an Icon with the size 120x120.

Comment: Unfortunately, even when I change to 1.4 I get the same errors. :( Will edit question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

The simple thing is you have to Archive the project again. Products > Archive and then Validate.