# App upload error: "The value for key CFBundleVersion must be a period-separated list of non-negative integers"

Tags: ios, xcode, upload

We're having an error uploading a new version of our app to the AppStore. When validating the archive we get the error message: "The value for key CFBundleVersion [2928M] in the Info.plist must be a period-separated list of non-negative integers. However checking the Version/Build settings as well as the plist file there is no wrong entry.
The earlier version numbers were:
Version: 1.2.2
Build:   1.2.2

New ones are:
Version: 2.2
Build:   2.2

so there is no hidden "number must be higher error". What confuses me is that when looking up this error, other people got their wrong input within the brackets in the error (2928M in our case) but I have absoluetly no clue where that thing comes from. I'd appreciate any hint. :)

Comment: Did you manually inspect the info.plist in the archive?

Comment: Please post your Info.plist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after some searching we found the error comes from the svn. It replaces the build number with its own and this one wasn't valid.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the build number should be an integer (so 2 or 3 in your case).

Did you see this answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6037025/2003734

HTH