# When uploading app the CFBundleShortVersionString field must be greater than the previous one

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm having this problem when uploading the new version to the store.

Previous build was (the latest successful update):

Version : 3.0

Build : 3.0.3

Before this there was :

Version : 3.0

Build : 3.0.2

Now I'm trying to load :

Version 3.0

Build : 3.0.4

Trying to upload this version I'm receiving the following error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key
CFBundleShortVersionString[3.0] in the Info.plist file must contain
a higher version than that of the previously approved version[3.0]."
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933093/cfbundleversion-in-the-info-plist-upload-error) post but it seems pretty old, and it talks about CFBundleVersion and not CFBundleShortVersionString..
I need to upload this as new build and not as new versione, this way it will be approved faster and I can test it.

If it can be helpful I'm using Xamarin studio.

Comment: Have you had a build of version 3.0 approved and released to the store?

Comment: Not released to the store... But released to testflight.. I Have 4 of them with Version 3.0 and they are in order(Build number) : 1.0 => 3.0.1 = > 3.0.2 => 3.0.3