# How to Allow Prospective Developer to Review/Test Live iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode

I have to solve the problem of how to allow review (testing) of our app by prospective developers, when the app is not yet Ad Hoc. I can't get it that far. Here's the problem:

I have to find a new developer to help update our app for 2016. It's a 365-day calendar of info that updates every year. The initial app download is a shell (free) in which 29 in-apps, each a different geographical region of information, can be purchased & downloaded. Regions are 16.95 each. In order to help candidates familiarize themselves with the app, they need to be able to download an in-app region and see the app function. I can't expect candidates to pay 16.95 for a region, so I need a way for them to test the app.

1: I can't use the promo code feature in iTunes Connect because it is worthless for in-app testing, which makes it worthless for many apps out there since the in-app is often where much of the critical content lies.

2: I can't sign candidates on as Sandbox or TestFlight testers because I can't upload the app into iTunes connect without getting an error message I don't know how to fix. When I try and submit the app through XCode or the App Uploader, I get an error reading, "The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleShortVersionString key." I don't know what to do with that error, so I can't get a version into the iTunes Connect environment to invite testers into.

Comment: Re: #2, what is the error you're getting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CFBundleVersion in the Info.plist Upload Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933093/cfbundleversion-in-the-info-plist-upload-error)

Comment: 1) Not sure what you are saying.  "It is worthless for in-app testing..." why?  I've used it for that before.  Where is the issue?  2) Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933093/cfbundleversion-in-the-info-plist-upload-error .  As an aside, there are various alternatives to TestFlight (google alternatives to TestFlight), but any discussion thereof is not topical to SO (library comparisons are not allowed).