# iOS CFBundleVersion version number, in Ionic apps

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, application-loader

I have the following in the config.xml of my ionic app:

```
<widget android-versionCode="1630" id="com.boardline" ios-CFBundleVersion="1630" version="1.63" versionCode="1630" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

but Application Loader gives me the following warning:

```
The value for the key CFBundleShortVersionString [1.63] in the info.plist must contain a higher version number...
```

whereas I explicitly put `ios-CFBundleVersion="1630"`...

Can you help me figure this out ? I need the ios CFBundle Version to be 1630 and the ionic app version to be 1.63.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/es/latest/config_ref/#versiones-adicionales)

```
// assuming version = MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH-whatever
versionCode = PATCH + MINOR * 100 + MAJOR * 10000
CFBundleVersion = "MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH"
```

Plus [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-version/)

```
this.appVersion.getVersionCode();
```

Could solve your problem (version code 1630 is not CFBundleVersion 1.63)
Otherwise, refer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933093/cfbundleversion-in-the-info-plist-upload-error).

Hope it helps.