# The info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleVersion key

Tags: swift, validation, swift2, plist, info.plist

I was trying to validate the app before uploading to apple with the new version and I'm getting this error:

"The info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleVersion key."

But what package? Could it be related to a framework?

Both keys are in the file so I don't know what's going on

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>en</string>
        <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
        <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>APPL</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>2.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
        <string>????</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>2.0</string>
        <key>Fabric</key>
        <dict>
            <key>APIKey</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>Kits</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>KitInfo</key>
                    <dict/>
                    <key>KitName</key>
                    <string>Crashlytics</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
        <false/>
        <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>comgooglemaps</string>
        </array>
        <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UIAppFonts</key>
        <array>
            <string>ProximaNova-Light.otf</string>
            <string>ProximaNova-Semibold.otf</string>
            <string>ProximaNova-Regular.otf</string>
            <string>ProximaNova-LightItalic.otf</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
        <array>
            <string>remote-notification</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
        <string>LaunchScreen</string>
        <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
        <string>Main</string>
        <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
        <array>
            <string>armv7</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
        <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Comment: Is this a native app and are you creating the archive using menu options or a tool? I've had this before when using xcodebuild

Comment: I'm using Xcode 7.3.1 to archive the app

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes iTunes connects conflicts you bundle version with the uploaded one(even if it is not published), so simply by bumping your current version from 2.0 to 2.1 or 3.0 might solve your problem, read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6037025/4744288) to know more about any other possible problem.